# Vectorize a conditional sum of elements in an array of indices and another array of elements to be added

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have 2 numpy array which might look like this: `n = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [4, 5, 5], [7, 7, 7]])` and `F = np.array([[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 1], [2, 3, 4]])`, where `n` is a matrix of indices and `F` is matrix of elements or values to be added to a result array. The `result` will be a 1D numpy array whose elements are the result of the sum over itself (starting with zero) and the corresponding values dictated by the indices in `n` and values in `F`. In other words, I want to vectorize the following operation:

```
n = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [4, 5, 5], [7, 7, 7]])
F = np.array([[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 1], [2, 3, 4]])

nmax = n.max()

result = np.zeros((nmax + 1,))
ravel_n = n.ravel()
ravel_F = F.ravel()
for i in range(n.shape[0] * n.shape[1]):
    if ravel_n[i] > 0:
        result[ravel_n[i]] = result[ravel_n[i]] + ravel_F[i]
```

This gives me

```
>>> result
[ 0.  5. 13.  0.  8. 10.  0.  9.]
```

I tried the following vectorized expression, but it outputs an incorrect result.

```
>>> result_2 = np.zeros((nmax + 1,))
>>> result_2[ravel_n[ravel_n > 0]] = result_2[ravel_n[ravel_n > 0]] + ravel_F[ravel_n > 0]
>>> result_2
[0. 5. 7. 0. 8. 1. 0. 4.]
```

What is the correct way of vectorizing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do with `bincount`:

```
np.bincount(n.ravel(), weights=F.ravel())
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.,  5., 13.,  0.,  8., 10.,  0.,  9.])
```